# Custom gradle plugin version resolved incorrectly

Tags: maven, gradle, versioning, gradle-plugin

I am using gradle 7.1.1. I created a Gradle plugin and publishing it into a local nexus repository. The version of the plugin will be of the format `0.1.1-<timestamp>`; So each build gets a new version value.

- In another Github repository, I am using the plugin by using dynamic
  versioning `0.1.+`;
- When I build and publish the plugin again, the plugin-consuming
  repository does not resolve the latest version. It resolves to `0.1.1-20211015165344`
- When I replace `0.1.+` with exact version (like `0.1.1-20211018102713`)
- I deleted ~/.gradle folder and also the `0.1.1-20211015165344` version from nexus. However I still get the same error.

**build.gradle** for plugin

```
gradlePlugin {
  plugins {
    customPluginTest {
      id = 'custom-plugin-test'
      implementationClass = 'com.mycompany.gradle.CustomPluginTest'
    }
  }
}
```

**`settings.gradle` from repository using the plugin**

```
  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
        maven {
          url = "${nexus_repo_base}/${nexus_pull_repo_m2}"
          credentials {
            username = nexus_username
            password = nexus_password
          }
        }
      gradlePluginPortal()
    }
  plugins {
    id 'custom-plugin-test' version "${pluginVersion}"
  }
}
```

- The `pluginVersion` is set in `gradle.properties` to `0.1.+`
- In `build.gradle` I have not used the `version` attribute of the plugin.

**Debug logs**

I tried running gradle with `--debug` flag but it did not help to find the root cause.

It just had these lines:

```
243 2021-10-18T10:46:35.478+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConfiguration2'     started
244 2021-10-18T10:46:35.481+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConf    iguration2'
245 2021-10-18T10:46:35.481+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of :classpath' started
246 2021-10-18T10:46:35.488+0530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://localhost/repository/development/com/mycompany/gradle/custom-plugin-test/0.1.1-20211015165344/custom-plugin-test-0.1.1-20211015165344.pom' started
```

Any thoughts where  `0.1.1-20211015165344` version is getting resolved from?